# canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") creates black area at the end of the image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using [qr.js (http://neocotic.com/qr.js)](http://neocotic.com/qr.js) to create **QRCodes**. I want to get my users the ability to download these **QRCodes**, therefore I need to create an image from the canvas-element, using the function toDataURL. Executing it with "image/png" functions without a problem, but when I try to create an JPEG-Image, it adds a black area at the end of the image:  [image]

Did anyone else get this problem too and knows a solution or has a possible reason why this problem occurs?

**Browser**: Google Chrome 24.0.1312.56, Mozilla Firefox 18.0.0.1

Comment: maybe it only supports png, makes sense to ask neocotic

Comment: I've downloaded one of JPEGs to see, if this is also visible on the "final" Image. And it is not. Could this perhaps be an problem with the browsers' engine? I'll try to contact neocotic, too, to see if he has a solution. :)

Comment: I scan ready their docs, not seeing anywhere it supports jpeg. Which makes sense as this is more of a vector image type. I suspect by stating it as a jpg, the file output is only named "jpg" but is still actually a png.

Comment: We need to see the actual code how you generate the image for possible bugs.